# Map and Combine JSON objects in Python

Tags: python, json

Still learning Python and trying to combine 2 JSON objects.

**Primary Data Set:**

```
{
    "form-fields": [
        {"type": "text", "x-position": 0, "y-position": 0, "field": "buyer-1"},
        {"type": "text", "x-position": 0, "y-position": 10, "field": "buyer-2"}
    ]
}
```

**Secondary Data Set:**

```
{
    "form-data": [
        {"field": "buyer-1", "value": "John Smith"},
        {"field": "buyer-2", "value": "Susan Smith"}
    ]
}
```

**Intended Result:**
*With "value" appended to the original object.*

```
{
    "form-fields": [
        {"type": "text", "x-position": 0, "y-position": 0, "field": "buyer-1", "value": "John Smith"},
        {"type": "text", "x-position": 0, "y-position": 10, "field": "buyer-2", "value": "Susan Smith"}
    ]
}
```

Comment: like merging element at first index with first index element..
and second with second index element?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that the fields are not in order between primary and secondary. The plan is to create a dictionary call `update` where key=field and value=secondary's value. Then update the primary.

```py
primary = {
    "form-fields": [
        {"type": "text", "x-position": 0, "y-position": 0, "field": "buyer-1"},
        {"type": "text", "x-position": 0, "y-position": 10, "field": "buyer-2"}
    ]
}

secondary = {
    "form-data": [
        {"field": "buyer-1", "value": "John Smith"},
        {"field": "buyer-2", "value": "Susan Smith"}
    ]
}

update = {
    record["field"]: record["value"]
    for record in secondary["form-data"]
}
# update is {'buyer-1': 'John Smith', 'buyer-2': 'Susan Smith'}

for record in primary["form-fields"]:
    if record["field"] in update:
        record["value"] = update[record["field"]]
```

The result is `primary` to become

```
{
    "form-fields": [
        {
            "type": "text",
            "x-position": 0,
            "y-position": 0,
            "field": "buyer-1",
            "value": "John Smith"
        },
        {
            "type": "text",
            "x-position": 0,
            "y-position": 10,
            "field": "buyer-2",
            "value": "Susan Smith"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Hai Vu - thanks so much for this great answer!  This was exactly what I was looking for.  I learned a lot from @Nandha's answer, but your solution makes more sense because the field's may not be in order and need to match exactly on their key values.  I marked your answer as the accepted answer.  Thanks a million sir!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming length and index will be same in both dictionaries,

```py
primary = {
    "form-fields": [
        {"type": "text", "x-position": 0, "y-position": 0, "field": "buyer-1"},
        {"type": "text", "x-position": 0, "y-position": 10, "field": "buyer-2"}
    ]
}

sec = {
    "form-data": [
        {"field": "buyer-1", "value": "John Smith"},
        {"field": "buyer-2", "value": "Susan Smith"}
    ]
}

pl = primary.get("form-fields")
sl = sec.get("form-data")

for index, prim_val in enumerate(pl):
    sec_val = sl[index]
    prim_val.update(sec_val)
    
print(primary)
```

Sample code for merging dictionaries

```py
marks = {'Physics':67, 'Maths':87}
internal_marks = {'Practical':48}

marks.update(internal_marks)


print(marks)

# Output: {'Physics': 67, 'Maths': 87, 'Practical': 48}
```

Comment: Nandha this was a very elegant solution.  Thank you so much for the thoughtful response!  I didn't know about enumerate, so I added print statements in the for loop for `print(index, prim_val)` and `print(sl[index])`.  I ended up accepting Hai Vu's answer only because the order might not be the same.  For example the buyer-2 might come before buyer-1 in the form-data.  I wasn't super specific in my original post, so apologies for that.  I definitely learned a lot from your answer with enumerate and the sample code for merging dictionaries.  Thank you!!!